# Firestore Rules to check if user liking post exists in users Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'd like to check if the user liking the post is already present in our users cloud Firestore.
There are two different collections here, need to check if one's reference is present in another.

Users collection has user details - UID/Name/Email
Posts collection has details : Post Text / Post Likes / Post Comments
Where Likes is an Map which has userId of person who has liked the image and userName.

From backend its possible to exploit the posts collection and enter malicious value in post documents.

I am trying to achieve this for ON UPDATE condition : To check the user liking post exists in users collection.

------ Tried Below So far but it doesnt work --------------------

```
match /posts/items/{document} 
   allow update: if exists(/database/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.resource.data.likes.userId));
```

What I want is to check if the users liking are already existing or not.
This doesnt work because the likes column is an array and can have multiple objects.

Any help would be great.

Comment: If I understand the question, the user posting the like will have a uid. If you want to verify they exist, the rule would allow the write if the uid exists in /users (assuming you have a users collection with the documentId's being all of the existing users uid's)

Comment: Yes, but using exist doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The rules in your question are incomplete which may be causing them to not work. See [Access Other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in the getting started guide as it's very similar to what you need.

Comment: every where its mentioned while trying to use exists to use auth.uid - however if I want to use request.resource.data.likes wouldnt that work with exist ?

Comment: You *can* use .exists but the rules showing in your question are not complete, please update the question with your complete rules - it should look like the ones I linked above. We don't know what *request.resource.data.likes* is - uid is a property of the auth variable, not a path as such.